# PassportJs Refreshing Session Variables?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using PassportJS with node to handle authentication.
If the authentication fails, I want the inputs to be temporarily saved so I can reload them again on the web page and display some sort of error message:

Passport Login Strategy:

```
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(
    {
        passReqToCallback: true,
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    async (req, email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOneByEmail(email);
            if (user) {
                const passwordsMatch = await PasswordHash.compare(password, user.password);
                if (passwordsMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            }

            console.log('Sending inputs back to the user : ' + req.sessionID);
            req.session.inputs = {
                email: email,
                . . . 
            }
            return done(null, false);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err);
        }
    });
```

Account Login Router: URL Structure in Express ('/accounts/*'):

```
accountsRouter.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('accounts/login.ejs', 
    { 
        inputs: req.session.inputs
    });

    console.log("BEFORE DELETE: " + req.session.inputs);
    delete req.session.inputs;
    console.log("AFTER DELETE: " + req.session.inputs);
});
```

I expected it to store the inputs and display them to the user once the login has failed. If the user hits refresh on Chrome (GET /accounts/login) rather than clicking on the login button again (POST /accounts/login), the req.session.inputs variable should be empty. However, for some reason the variable is maintaining its value when refreshing the browser, even though the console is showing that the variable had been deleted.

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
# Getting the login page (blank fields)
BEFORE DELETE: undefined
AFTER DELETE:  undefined
GET /accounts/login 200 7.042 ms - 2327

# Click the login button
Sending inputs back to the user : Km2o9VFTWkvQxsz28Tt7Tx9mzL2NS14f
POST /accounts/login 302 31.850 ms - 74

# Login fails, displaying inputs back to user. Delete variable on render
BEFORE DELETE: [object Object]
AFTER DELETE: undefined
GET /accounts/login 200 3.919 ms - 2338

# Hits Chrome refresh on login page, req.session.inputs should be undefined here but it's not?
BEFORE DELETE: [object Object]
AFTER DELETE: undefined
GET /accounts/login 200 2.404 ms - 2338
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that it was not just in Passport but in general with Express Session. Found out that you must call `await req.session.save();` or any changes are only made locally and will not be saved in the session store.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the browser is caching the input values.

When you render your view explicitly set your input values like this:

```
<input type="text" name="textfield" value="">
```

Comment: I have a feeling that it's more server-side. If the browser was just caching the text, then it wouldn't be showing that the session variable still has a defined obj on the refresh.

Comment: I think you are right it must be in Express. Don't you render the view before actually deleting? Maybe just change the order.